# Conexão de rede não funciona depois de um tempo de ociosidade. (Socket error 10050)

Tags: totalcross

Olá,

O problema descrito ocorre nas plataformas windows mobile. Testado nos equipamentos: CN50, CN51, MC65, MC67.

Como produzir o erro:

- Instalo uma app em um dos equipamentos descritos acima.
- Reinicio o equipamento
- Faço testes de conexão pela app, via Wireless e GPRS  (Criando um socket e trocando dados com o mesmo)
- Deixo o equipamento por um tempo ocioso (cerca de 1h)
- Clico no botão para fazer o teste novamente. O erro de socket 10050 começa a aparecer.

Este erro também ocorre quando mudo o tipo de conexão. Ex: O equipamento está conectado via cabo no computador e retiro o cabo fazendo com que o equipamento utilize as conexões wirless (wifi ou GPRS)

Procedimentos para tentar solucionar:

- Sai da app e desliguei a interface wireless e tentei apenas pelo GPRS (não deu certo)
- Sai da app e desliguei a interface gprs e tentei apenas pelo wireless (não deu certo)
- Sai da app, religuei a interface wireless e gprs, abri o internet explorer, entrei em um endereço web, em seguida abri a app e testei a conexão  (deu certo).

APP:

A aplicação basicamente cria um socket com um servidor, não executo nenhuma operação de solicitar conexão tipo ConnectionManager.open() antes de criar o 
socket, pois vi que está deprecated.

É necessário utilizar o ConnectionManager para dispositivos com windows mobile ?